# Unable to hide view in SecondViewController class by calling function in FirstViewController Class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Function call in FirstViewController is -

```
@IBAction func redViewAct(sender :UIButton) {
        let nextview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController1
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextview, animated: true)
       let f1 = ViewController1()
        f1.view1Show()
    }
```

Method in second class -

```
@IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blackview: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func view1Show() {
        redView.hidden = false
        blackview.hidden = true
    }
```

Comment: It Show - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You can do it by using `NSNotificationCenter` also

Comment: Why are you creating two ViewController1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like below, FirstViewController,

```
@IBAction func redViewAct(sender :UIButton) {
    let nextview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController1
    nextview.flag = "showView"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextview, animated: true)

}
```

In Second view,

```
@IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var blackview: UIView!
var flag : String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(self.flag == "showView")
    {
        redView.hidden = false
        blackview.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: set colon `:` with selector method as i did in viewDidLoad and name of nsnotification will be same in viewDidLoad and in PostNotification of button click

Comment: Ok it may occurs because of that both views are not initialise before calling that method. so there is other option to make is that we have to pass something like flag while doing segue so we can achieve this